# Usage of CustomEditor with BeanWrapperFieldExtractor just like with BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper

Tags: spring-batch

I have written a simple Spring Batch application that reads a CSV file, does some transforming and writes a modified CSV to the disk.

The reading of the file into domain objects works like a charm. I use *DelimitedLineTokenizer* to tokenize the lines and a *BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper* to feed the values into a bean:

```
<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['inputResource']}" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                    <property name="names"
                        value="ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,PRICE,DATE" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="targetType" value="myapp.MyDomainObject" />
                    <property name="customEditors">
                        <map>
                            <entry key="java.util.Date" value-ref="dateEditor" />
                            <entry key="java.math.BigDecimal" value-ref="numberEditor" />
                        </map>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I especially like the features of *BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper* to "guess" the field names and the possibility to define *CustomEditors* which I use to define the special date and number formats used in the input file.

Now I would like to write the modified file in the same format like the input file. 
I use the following configuration:

```
<bean id="writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['outputResource']}" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="id,name,description,price,date" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There are two things I miss with this configuration:

1. *BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper* allowed me to set *CustomEditors*, but *BeanWrapperFieldExtractor* has no such possibility. Is there a way to use these?
2. Is there a way to define the headings in the first line of the file? I have not found any way to write an initial line that is not a bean... It would be great to use the same names here as in *BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper* such that *BeanWrapperFieldExtractor* writes the inital line and guesses the bean property namens as *BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper* does.

The process to load files is so comfortable in Spring Batch. Why is the writing of files so different? Am I missing something?

I have to use Spring Batch 2.1.x because we are using Spring 3.0.x . Therefor an upgrade to 2.2.x would not be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Which is your need? Extract field property as text? You can

   - use a `FormatterLineAggregator` if you needs are not too complicated
   - write your own `CustomEditorsFieldExtractor` (better)
   - Generate a complex domain object composed by original domain object and by text-formatted object and use last one as parameter of writer (but breaks your current processor/writer)
2. Use `FlatFileItemWriter.headerCallback`: if setted allow custom header write

Writing - in your case - seems a pain respect read process because spring-batch's reading components fits your needs.
 Standard components fits more used use-case and they cover a lot of scenario. Let us write a custom FieldExtractor sometimes! :)

Comment: I tried your first solution on 1. and the Format String is really really ugly (for my real world data bean, not the example above): `<property name="format" value="%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%f;%f;%s;%f;%f;%td.%&lt;tm.%&lt;tY;%td.%&lt;tm.%&lt;tY;%s;%td.%&lt;tm.%&lt;tY;%s;%s;%s;%s;%td.%&lt;tm.%&lt;tY" />` Seems like I will have to implement my own Extractor. This is really annoying as it would be so simple to define some CustomEditors. Don't get why reading a CSV is a common use case but writing one is a special case?

Comment: IDK, and check [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?122524-Reading-and-Writing-Beans-with-custom-PropertyEditors); if they don't offers this extractor probably there will be some serious reasons... and if you write your own extract share with friends ;D
Good luck

Comment: Yes, the forum question is the same as mine. But unfortunately there is no answer for it. Thanks anyway. The first two suggestions for 1. would be possible depending on the complexity of the conversion. I had not accepted because I had no chance to check the answer for 2. Will do it today.